# Gamma function and product of $\int_0^\pi \sin^k x\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, gamma-function

I want to prove that:
\begin{equation}
\pi \prod_{k=1}^{n-2}\int_0^\pi\sin^kx\,dx=\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)},\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{equation}
I have set:
$$ I_k:=\int_0^\pi\sin^kx\,dx,\quad\forall k\in\mathbb{N},$$
then, by integration by part:
$$ I_k:=\frac{k-1}{k}I_{k-2},\quad\forall k\in\mathbb{N}. $$
At this points i haven't any idea to go on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Solve the recurrence equation $I_k= \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \;\Gamma \left(\frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{k}{2}+1\right)}$

Comment: Can you give me the details please?

Comment: I solved $k\,a_k  = \left( {k - 1} \right)a_{k - 2} ;a_0  = \pi ;a_1  = 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the trigonometric form of the beta function, which reads
$$2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m-1}x\cos^{2n-1}x\:dx=\frac{\Gamma(m)\:\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}$$
Setting $m=\frac{k+1}{2}$ and $n=\frac{1}{2}$, we obtain
$$2\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^k x\:dx=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)\:\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+2}{2}\right)}$$
Since $\sin(\pi-x) = \sin x$, we have
$$I_k\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\int_0^{\pi}\sin^kx\:dx=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^k x\:dx=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)\:\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+2}{2}\right)}$$
Now, we would like to determine the product
$$\begin{align} 
\pi\:\prod_{k=1}^{n-2}I_k &= \pi\:\prod_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)\:\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+2}{2}\right)}
\\ 
&= \pi\:\frac{\Gamma(1)\:\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)} 
\\
&=\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}
\end{align} $$
The problem is solved.

Comment: Why $\prod_{k=1}^{n-2}\Gamma( (k+1)/2 )=\Gamma(1)$ and $\prod_{k=1}^{n-2}\Gamma((k+2)/2)=\Gamma(n/2)$?

Comment: No, the product telescopes to $\frac{\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(n/2)}$

Comment: $$\prod_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+2}{2}\right)}=\frac{\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(3/2)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(2)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(2)}{\Gamma(5/2)}\cdot\cdots\cdot\frac{\Gamma((n-1)/2)}{\Gamma(n/2)}$$ Can you see the cancellation?